# wxMessageBox() class from wxWIdgets (3.1.4) before wxEntry(argc, argv); Alert use to missing CPU instruction sets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

My application is written in C++ and it's UI is written in wxWidgets.

Some of my routines use specific instruction sets (AVX, AVX2, SSE1, SSE2, SSE3, SSE4 etc). I have written some of these instructions myself but others are coming in via Automatic vectorization (gcc -march=haswell). This, of course, causes problems with older CPUs. If, for example, my application is run on a CPU that does not have AVX then it produces a SIGILL.

I've got around this problem by using Google's *cpu_features* library (https://github.com/google/cpu_features) to check for specific instruction sets and, if any are missing, then I show a simple message box to alert the user and then terminate the application.

I am using the following code to check the CPU:

```
#include "cpuinfo_x86.h"
static const cpu_features::X86Features features = cpu_features::GetX86Info().features;
bool __attribute__((optimize("O0"))) is_cpu_supported(int argc, char **argv)
{

// #ifdef __LINUX__
// gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
// #endif

    if (!features.avx || !features.avx2 || !features.sse4_1 || !features.fma3 || ...)
    {
         // Alert the user to missing instruction sets and terminate
         #ifdef __LINUX__
         gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
         #endif

         wxMessageBox("Missing instruction set");
         return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I use `__attribute__((optimize("O0")))` to make absolutely sure that this particular function will not get optimised so that I know it should run on any x86-64 CPU. The `is_cpu_supported()` function is run at the very start of `main()` and before wxWidgets is fully initialised.

For this to work, I need a very lightweight, platform independent and simple function to display a standard message box to the user. As you can see, I am currently using `wxMessageBox()` to alert the user but my concerns are that I am calling `wxMessageBox()` before `wxIMPLEMENT_APP_NO_MAIN(MainApp);` and `wxEntry(argc, argv);` are fully active. This seems to work on Linux (wxWidgets linked against gtk3), Windows and macOS. Although Linux requires  `gtk_init(&argc, &argv);`.

As mentioned above, this seems to work on all my target platforms. However, I would like to ask if calling `wxMessageBox()` before  `wxEntry(argc, argv);` is likely to cause undefined behaviour?

Many thanks
Amanda

Comment: Why not do this check in your App::OnInit method.  That way you know the wxWidgets library is ready for use.  You can do your check, and if it fails you can show your message box followed by return false.  Returning false from OnInit will cause the program to exit.  If the check succeeds, you can proceed with your normal OnInit method.

Comment: @NewPagodi I could put the CPU checks in OnInit() but that moves my checks further up the call stack (in my application, after SDL2 is instantiated). I would prefer my CPU checks to take place before anything else happens.

Comment: @Amanda, when is the first CPU-related function is executed? Also, you already have a piece f code that might give you a problem - `gtk_init()` call is also done by wxWidgets. So yes - I'd move it to the wxApp::OnInit() and see whether any failures will be produced..

Comment: @Igor Apologies, The example code I posted was wrong.  gtk_init() should have been placed inside the if statement. I'll look into doing these checks in OnInit().